# Excel sheet to store into database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want to know how to store the excel sheet(like payslip it's contain image also) into sql server 2005 database using asp.net

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using a BLOB field:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Store_and_manipulat_BLOBs.aspx

or just store the sheet in a properly protected directory and serve it up via a ASHX handler when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using SQL Server 2008 or later, you would also have the option of using [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) storage.

Answer (score 0):

We use varbinary(max) for storing documents in sql server. Load the document as a byte array.